# Getting Received fatal alert: handshake_failure exception in java 1.7.0_80

Tags: java, java-7, tls1.2, sha256, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to call ups server for some rate related details. Recently they migrated to new Ciphers.
For some reason we can not update our jdk version, so we need to stick to 1.7.0_80.
I am getting below stack trace when calling ups calls

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring disabled protocol: SSLv3
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1635344196 bytes = { 88, 0, 128, 81, 194, 87, 28, 140, 174, 104, 190, 184, 32, 3, 190, 29, 68, 66, 220, 248, 56, 153, 156, 98, 76, 74, 32, 115 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: onlinetools.ups.com]
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 221
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
```

API call is as below

```
try {
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            URL url = new URL("https://onlinetools.ups.com/......");
            HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            uc.setDoOutput(true);
            uc.setDoInput(true);
            uc.setUseCaches(false);
            outputStream = uc.getOutputStream(); //Exception getting thrown from here
            outputStream.write(xmlInputString.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
                int letter = 0;
                while ((letter = reader.read()) != -1) {
                    buffer.append((char) letter);
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error reading UPS response"+ e);
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                    reader = null;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("response is :"+ buffer.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

xmlInputString is the request string.

Already tried with bouncycastle but no luck and updated security jars(local_policies and other jar).
Please provide the suggestions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: #1 Enable more verbose log `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and try again. Share us if log has new important lines. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/973783 #2 open-jdk 8 is not an option?

Comment: @JRichardsz, Thank you for your response. I added a -D argument and extracted below comments and updated in question. Yes, open-jdk 8 is not an option because the above mentioned code snippet is from a very big project and it is like very major effort to migrate to java 8.

Comment: try with this `java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1`

Comment: @JRichardsz, we already have that argument. After that argument we are getting hans shake exception. Before that the error is "protocl_version"

Comment: That server supports only ciphersuites using GCM; Java 7 JSSE supports TLS1.2 if prodded (e.g. with `https.protocols`) but not GCM suites. Bouncy (bctls&bcprov) 1.68 or 1.67 context `"TLSv1.2"` WORKS FOR ME on 7u80 except I have to fix the truststore because that server uses a CA (Comodo RSA) not in 7u80 cacerts. (1.69 seems to have some internal inconsistency; 1.66 and 1.65 don't offer the GCM suites even though they're listed; 1.64 and below have some problem with SecureRandom I don't understand.) But if youi found an alternative, fine.

Answer (score 0):

As we didn't find any solid information to proceed with this using java 7, we had a microservice running on open jdk 11. So we are caling that micro service internally and doing an actual call.